# In sql server - report server URL acces denied error

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008

when trying to open report server url http://<>/Report server
i am getting error 
/ does not have enough permissions rsAcessdenied  error.
how to add domain account in reporting services to get all the privileges so that i can open the report server URL.

Comment: This is a good question for ServerFault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the management screen at http://<>/Reports using an account with admin access.
Ask your SQL Server DBA what account to use or get them to do this.

Then click on the properties tab, click new role assignment, and add the account which is getting the access denied message (It probably just needs the browser role.)